# Proving that a given group action is Transitive.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-actions

We need to prove that the symmetric group $S_n$ acts transitively in it's usual action as permutations on $ A = \{ 1,2,3,....,n \}$.

We know that the action of a group $G$ is called transitive if there is only one orbit(Number of equivalence classes of an element).

Also , index of a stabilizer of an element gives the number of elements in the equivalence class of that element.

So , my approach is , if I somehow show that $G_i$ which is the stabilizer of any point $i$ in $A$ has index $n$ then our job is done.

$G_i =  s \in S_n | s \cdot i = i $ ,

But how to show that it has index $n$ ?

Or how to show it has $n$ number of cosets ? Could anyone help ?

Comment: Take $a,b\in A=\{1,2,3,\ldots,n\}$. Can you find $\sigma\in S_n$ such that $\sigma(a)=b$?

Comment: Yeah, you don't need any bells and whistles or theorems about stabilizers, just definitions.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Notice that the cycle $(k,l)\in S_n$ for any $k,l\in \{1,2,..,n\}$.

Answer (score 0):

It's way more simple. For every $i,j\in A$, the map $\sigma$ swapping $i$ and $j$ (and fixing all the other elements of $A$) is a bijection on $A$, namely it's an element of $S_n$. This suffices to prove that the action is transitive.

Anyway, pursuing your approach: $G_i=\{\sigma\in S_n\mid \sigma(i)=i\}$ has clearly order $(n-1)!$ (and hence index $n$ in $S_n$), essentially by the standard argument used to show the $S_n$ has order $n!$.