# Prove that $A_n$, the set of even permutations on a set of length n, is a transitive group of transformations on $S=\{1,2,3,...,n\}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I already know that $S_n$ is a transitive group of transformations on $S=\{1,2,3,...,n\}$. I am sure that it has to be with the fact that $A_n \subset S_n$ but I do not how to proceed.

Comment: What is given about $n$ ? This is manifestly false for $n = 2$.

Comment: See question Q3 [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2346139/is-group-action-of-alternating-group-transitive-and-primitive).

Comment: @darijgrinberg, I am sorry. This is for n$\geq$ 3